# Java ProxyServlet destroys filename encoding

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-proxy

I am using a Java Proxy Servlet that forwards any http request to a server based using Apache httpClient. It works nice, but filenames, that using special characters like "öÖäÄüÜß" get corrupted.

**Browser sends**

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="lp_fos_fr-ööÖÖääÄÄüüÜÜß_technik.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

**After forwarding the request by ServletProxy**

```
HttpEntityEnclosingRequest eProxyRequest =
            new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest(method, proxyRequestUri);
eProxyRequest.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(servletRequest.getInputStream(), servletRequest.getContentLength()));
```

The filename is corrupted:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="lp_fos_fr-.........................._technik.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

What could I do to preserve the filename?

Comment: Can you try with Content-Type: application/pdf;charset=UTF-8. I think it is an charset issue

Comment: After some more investigation i found out that the problem resists inside resteasy handling of the http request. Therefore i created a new question with new details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401395/resteasy-destroys-filename-encoding-on-multipart-form-data-post-requests