# Resteasy destroys filename encoding on multipart/form-data POST requests

Tags: file-upload, character-encoding, resteasy

I do a fileupload to the following annotated Restservice

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadFile")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input)
```

When special characters in the filename like "äÄöÖüÜß" are used, the filename gets corrupted during processing of Resteasy subsystem.

I verified this by creating a Logginginterceptor

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class LoggingInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor
```

Inside this interceptor, the http fileupload (multipart/form-data) is still correct

*Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="**TestäÄöÖüÜßFile2.pdf**"
Content-Type: application/pdf*

when Resteasy calls the uploadFile Method, the filename is corrupted

*Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="**Test��������������File2.pdf**"
Content-Type: application/pdf*

Is there a possibility (maybe by some annotation) to preserve the filename encoding in the Entity?

Kind regards

Shane

Comment: Having the same issue and didn't find a solution yet...

Comment: Found this: http://www.kurtsparber.de/?p=337

But didn't work for me on JBoss EAP 6.3. Maybe it does for you!